# Same code (using R's dplyr, stringr, and sf) produces different results when using different package versions

Tags: r, dplyr, version, stringr, r-sf

I am trying to run the same R code using computers that different versions of packages, but in one of them the code works and in the other it produces an error.

Specifically, I downloaded files from [this link](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_RD18/LAYER/CD/) and combined `stringr`'s `str_remove` function with `dplyr`'s `rename_with` function to rename variables in a data frame of class `sf` (so I can have variable names standardized according to names that I have in other files). The code that I ran was the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(stringr)

dft <- st_read(file.path('D:', 'Downloads', 'tl_rd22_01_cd118.shp'), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  rename_with(., .fn = str_remove, pattern = '\\d{2}$')
```

In one of the computers the code ran as expected (removing digits at the end of the name of some variables), but in the other computer it produced the following error message (when translated to English):

```
Error in .fn(names(agr)) : argument "pattern" missing, no pattern
```

However, in the computer that displayed an error, the following code works.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(stringr)

dft <- st_read(file.path('D:', 'Downloads', 'tl_rd22_01_cd118.shp'), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry(.) %>%
  rename_with(., .fn = str_remove, pattern = '\\d{2}$')
```

The problem with this solution is that I loose the geometry column.
This error message does not seem to make sense to me. The problem seems to be with the versions that I have in the two computers. In the one that worked, the versions of `dplyr`, `stringr`, and `sf` are 1.0.7, 1.4.0, and 1.0.3, respectively; in the one that did not work, they are 1.1.4, 1.5.1, and 1.0.14. For me, it seems that there is some incompatibility between `replace_with` and objects of class `sf`.

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please?  with `dplyr` version 1.1.4, `mtcars |> rename_with(.fn=str_remove, pattern = ".$")` does work ...

Comment: The NEWS file is your friend. https://stringr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#stringr-100 reveals that `str_remove` didn't exist before stringr 1.3.0. This might be related to your problem.

Comment: @dash2 OP states that their `stringr` versions are 1.4.0 and 1.5.1, so both > 1.3.0.

Comment: The simplest solution is to update packages. The robust solution is to use a tool like `renv` to enable you to ensure your code is run with a static package version on any system. If you insist on tracking down the source of the discrepancy, then you should do some debugging. Does `str_remove` work alone? Does `rename_with` work alone? Test on simple built-in data, not large downloaded data.

Comment: @BenBolker, using the `mtcars` dataset worked smoothly in both computers that I am using. Apparently, the `rename_with` function does not work properly with an object of class `sf`. Indeed, based on your suggestion, I tried my code on both computers, but I dropped the geometry column to see what would happen. When doing this, I got the expected results with both computers. (I checked the versions of `sf` in both computers; the one that did not work has version 1.0.14, and the one that worked has version 1.0.3.) In summary, the problem seems to be the difference in versions of `sf`.

Comment: @GregorThomas, thanks for the suggested solution. But the problem of updating packages is that the most recent of the two versions is the one causing problems. So updating it would not seem to solve my problem. As mentioned in my reply to @BenBolker, the problem seems to be with using `rename_with` with an object of class `sf` (with version is 1.0.14, which is a more recent version). Given that the problem now seems to be with `rename_with`, I am looking for an alternative to it. (I am also curious about why it is not working with a recent version of `sf`.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch in your question that it's the recent version causing trouble. I would say it's still not clear whether the issue is with the version of `sf` or the version of `dplyr`. A little more testing could isolate that. Or you could rename your columns more directly with a loop. Or you could downgrade packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sf` has a new method: `rename_with.sf` as of version [1.0-13](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/main/NEWS.md#version-10-13):

```r
sf:::rename_with.sf
#> function (.data, .fn, .cols, ...) 
#> {
#>     if (!requireNamespace("rlang", quietly = TRUE)) 
#>         stop("rlang required: install that first")
#>     .fn = rlang::as_function(.fn)
#>     agr = st_agr(.data)
#>     ret = NextMethod()
#>     names(agr) = .fn(names(agr))
#>     st_agr(ret) = agr
#>     ret
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x00000235ee991c48>
#> <environment: namespace:sf>
```

This means that the `...` isn't passed to the function in this case, as it is with `rename_with.data.frame`:

```r
dplyr:::rename_with.data.frame
#> function (.data, .fn, .cols = everything(), ...) 
#> {
#>     .fn <- as_function(.fn)
#>     cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(.cols), .data, allow_rename = FALSE)
#>     names <- names(.data)
#>     sel <- vec_slice(names, cols)
#>     new <- .fn(sel, ...)
#>     if (!is_character(new)) {
#>         cli::cli_abort("{.arg .fn} must return a character vector, not {.obj_type_friendly {new}}.")
#>     }
#>     if (length(new) != length(sel)) {
#>         cli::cli_abort("{.arg .fn} must return a vector of length {length(sel)}, not {length(new)}.")
#>     }
#>     names <- vec_assign(names, cols, new)
#>     names <- vec_as_names(names, repair = "check_unique")
#>     set_names(.data, names)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x00000235ee381aa0>
#> <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

For a working approach, you could try using a `purrr` function to explicitly pass the arguments:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_RD18/LAYER/CD/tl_rd22_01_cd118.zip", "tl_rd22_01_cd118.zip")

unzip("tl_rd22_01_cd118.zip")

st_read('tl_rd22_01_cd118.shp', quiet = TRUE) |> 
  rename_with(~ str_remove(.x, pattern = '\\d{2}$')) 
#> Simple feature collection with 7 features and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -88.47323 ymin: 30.14442 xmax: -84.88825 ymax: 35.00803
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#>   STATEFP GEOID CD118FP                 NAMELSAD LSAD CDSESSN MTFCC FUNCSTAT
#> 1      01  0101      01 Congressional District 1   C2     118 G5200        N
#> 2      01  0102      02 Congressional District 2   C2     118 G5200        N
#> 3      01  0103      03 Congressional District 3   C2     118 G5200        N
#> 4      01  0104      04 Congressional District 4   C2     118 G5200        N
#> 5      01  0105      05 Congressional District 5   C2     118 G5200        N
#> 6      01  0106      06 Congressional District 6   C2     118 G5200        N
#> 7      01  0107      07 Congressional District 7   C2     118 G5200        N
...
```

Or explicitly use the `dplyr:::rename_with.data.frame` method in your function call:

```r
st_read('tl_rd22_01_cd118.shp', quiet = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr:::rename_with.data.frame(., .fn = str_remove, pattern = '\\d{2}$')
```

### Edit - suggested fix

I'd suggest a potential GitHub fix as I think the easiest tweak would be to change [this line](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/99d6565a95e293b61f59002e8518dc3141ff1404/R/tidyverse.R#L272) from:

```r
names(agr) = .fn(names(agr))
```

to:

```r
names(agr) = .fn(names(agr), ...)
```

Comment: Arguably, the incompatibility is a bug in `sf`, or at least an issue worth raising there.

Comment: Indeed that seems a good next step. I have a bad habit of jumping in and 'taking credit' for a bug someone else has discovered though! Will open issue and pull request on Monday if OP is happy for me to do that :)

Comment: @AndyBaxter, I'll be really happy if you can do that. I'm not familiar with opening issues on GitHub. If you can do that, it will be really helpful for those using the `sf` package.